# Linq to Sql Foreign key relationships

Tags: sql, linq, foreign-keys, intellisense, relationship

Table name: `Author`

- AuthorID -> primary key
- FirstName
- LastName

Table name: `Titles`

- ISBN -> primary key
- BookTitle
- EditionNumber
- CopyRight

Table name: `AuthorISBN`

- ISBN -> foreign key
- AuthorID -> foreign key

How come the below code block below does not trigger the intellisense, since Linq-to-SQL automatically creates properties based on foreign-key relationship? In my case it doesn't...

ERROR:

> *The name title does not exist in current context in title.AuthorISBN*
>
> *It's not letting me add a photo, but 'Author' has 'one-to-many' relationship with AuthorISBN, and 'Titles' also has 'one-to-many' relationship with AuthorISBN*

Code:

```
 BooksDataContext database = new BooksDataContext();
 var authorsAndTitles =
          from title in database.Titles
          from book in title.AuthorISBN
          let author = book.Author
          orderby author.LastName, aurthor.FirstName, title.BookTitle
          select new { author.FirstName, author.LastName, title.BookTitle };
```

Comment: Table name 'Title' or 'titles' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you made a typo:

```
 var authorsAndTitles =
          from title in database.Titles
          from book in **tilte**.AuthorISBN
          let author = book.Author
          orderby author.LastName, aurthor.FirstName, title.BookTitle
          select new { author.FirstName, author.LastName, title.BookTitle };
```

Shouldn't it be title.AuthorISBN insteand of tilte.AuthorISBN? I surrounded the word with **.

Besides that, I would try this:

```
var authorsAndTitles =
          from title in database.Titles
          let author = title.AuthorISBN.Author
          orderby author.LastName, aurthor.FirstName, title.BookTitle
          select new { author.FirstName, author.LastName, title.BookTitle };
```

New attempt:

```
var authorsAndTitles =
          from autISBN in database.AuthorISBN
          let author = autISBN.Author
          let title = autISBN.Titles
          orderby author.LastName, author.FirstName, title.BookTitle
          select new { author.FirstName, author.LastName, title.BookTitle };
```

Comment: Yes in that case it was a typo, but does not make any difference when changed to the correct "title" nice of you to notice :)

Comment: What you say in regards to "let author = title.AuthorISBN.Author" makes sense, however, the intellisense doesn't bring up AuthorISBN after the ".", although I have confirmed the foreign-key relationship between Title/Author Tables to columns in AuthorISBN Table :(

Comment: New attempt, from a different starting point. I hope this is the good one! :)

Comment: new attempt does not work either:( it is not recognizing autISBN.Author and autISBN.Titles. I have enclosed my ORM for your review, maybe there's an issue in the relationship..