# Unable to create properties based on foreign-key relationship in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Table name: `Author`

- AuthorID -> primary key
- FirstName
- LastName

Table name: `Titles`

- ISBN -> primary key
- BookTitle
- EditionNumber
- CopyRight

Table name: `AuthorISBN`

- ISBN -> foreign key
- AuthorID -> foreign key

I can do:

```
var AuthorsAndISBNs =
            from author in database.Author
            join books in database.AuthorISBN
                on author.AuthorID equals books.AuthorID
            orderby author.LastName, author.FirstName
            select new { author.FirstName, author.LastName, books.ISBN };
```

However, I cannot do:

```
var authorsAndTitles =
           from title in database.Titles
           from book in title.AuthorISBN
           let author = book.Author
           orderby author.LastName, author.FirstName, title.BookTitle
           select new { author.FirstName, author.LastName, title.BookTitle };
```

I thought LINQ automatically creates properties based on foreign-key relationships,  which enables you to easitly access related rows in other tables:(

> Author has one-to-many relationship with AuthorISBN which has 'many-to-one' relationship with Titles

Please help! been stuck on this for days:'( THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you post your domain objects (Title, Author, and AuthorISBN)? Are you writing these classes by hand or using a tool to generate them?

Comment: Duplicate of [Linq to Sql Foreign key relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501285/linq-to-sql-foreign-key-relationships) - you've **just asked** this same question only 5 hours ago - please **do not** post the same question over and over again!

Comment: @Chasemedallion no I am not writing the classes by hand. I have already developed the tables in mySQL added the connection to my program in c#, and used object relational mapping (omr) to drag-and-drop them into a dbml file called Books.dbml. This method created a BookDataContext Object automatically to connect to my database.

Comment: @marc_s ok, i will not re-post it again. i'm just really frustrated over this

Comment: If query #1 works - why not use the same approach (using a `join` rather than two separate `from` clauses) for your second query?

Comment: @marc_s I have tried query#1, but distinct authors, and titles will not generate; just repetition of the same authors, and same BookTitle. And, I really want to resolve and understand this issue because it should let me access the other tables

Comment: You say you drug and dropped the tables into the dbml. Did it detect the associations (join?) If not, try adding that and see if you can then navigate through the object graph.

Comment: @JimWooley yes Jim that is what I did, it did detect the association by showing the relationship amongst the tables. at least, that is what the graph, a uml like, graph showed tables are connected. I try to delete the relationship and again add the association by right-clicking on the table, then add, then association but did not work:( what do you recommend? if that's what doped my table, what can I do to fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: You can drag the association line from the toolbox onto the classes in question. Make sure to set the cardinality and direction correctly. FWIW, you can check out the [LINQ in Action samples via LINQPad](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/LINQ-In-Action-Samples-available-in-LINQPad.aspx) which models books and authors with a similar structure to see if that can give you any additional clues. Also, if you want you can send me your dbml by emailing jimwooley @at hotmail if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order for LINQ let you access related rows in other tables, every table MUST have a PrimaryID. The issue was that 'AuthorISBN' Table did not have a primaryID, therefore no properties were being created:)